# ALIZE/LIA_RAL Toolkit 3.0 Tutorial

Tags: voice-recognition, speaker

I am trying get started with ALIZE/LIA_RAL Toolkit. Tried to run ALIZE3.0 Tutorial 02_i-vector_system_with_ALIZE3.0 on my system. But there might be some problem with data. Data folder with the I-vector system is empty and I have used data you provided with GMM-UBM tutorial. IvTest_WCCN_Cosine.log file is showing the following error -

```
[ Exception 0x77ce00 ]
  message   = "Matrix is not positive definite"
  source file = DoubleSquareMatrix.cpp
  line number = 177
```

Can you please help me out to fix this problem?

Comment: The exception information is not enough. I think it's maybe because your data is not enough to use the i-vector method. What's more, you can refer to the `./iv/raw/` folder to look the corresponding input data matrix.

Comment: Right you are. But I can not access to this file's (.y). Extension is unknown.